# Displaying shapefiles in Google Maps Android

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, google-maps-api, android

I want to develop an Android app which will display Google Maps and also display a shapefile (Esri shapefile with polygons, styled in ArcGIS, and having an attribute table). I want to be able to display the shapefile so that if someone clicks a polygon in the shapefile it brings up the attribute of that polygon.

Is this possible in Google Maps Android API, if not what are the other alternatives?

Comment: Alternatives, use a WMS or WFS

Comment: Any working example?

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

Yes, that is normal work that you can do this. First you should export your Shapefiles to a `Spatialite` database. You can download [Spatialite-GUI](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index#:%7E:text=spatialite%2Dgui%20is%20an%20open,librasterlite2) for do this. Then you can add these records to map and get any record from database with click on map. I am working with [Mapsforge VTM](https://github.com/mapsforge/vtm) instead of Google Map.

**Second Method:**

You can use Geoserver to generate a WMS layer and then show that in your application.

Comment: i want to have an independent application not using any external dbms , i think by your answer you mean i need to have the db running on a server somewhere, plus i cant use geoserver for same reasons, i dont want to have commuication with the server, just an app which has shapefiles stored locally..

Comment: You can use "First Method" to save your shapefile in a local database. Then retrieve that and show it on the map. You don't need to use Geoserver and communication with the server by this method.